# How much control can a site have over links opened in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I am creating a site which makes use of youtube videos, but I don't want to use the embedded player, I want to just have a youtube page in an IFRAME. I read the youtube TOS and I am not sure whether IFRAMES are allowed other than the embedded player so taking no chances I think I will build the site to open links in new tabs instead.  What I would really like is to be able to open new links in just one tab. To clarify, my site is tab 1, once a link is clicked youtube opens in tab 2, any further links clicked on my site replace the content in tab 2, and no more than 2 tabs will exist.

Comment: You can do this by treating the second window as a popup. Some users may choose to have popups open in new tabs but you can't guarantee that - it's up to the user and browser. You can re-use the popup/tab by giving it a name when you open it and using the same name on subsequent calls. None of this will stop a user right-clicking a link and choosing "Open in new tab"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube and some other high-profile websites block the use of iFrame for security reasons. So if you used an iFrame, it would just load blank.

To open a link to a new tab you would use:

```
<a href="/example.html" target="_blank">Open me!</a>
```

I'm not entirely sure that you can control which tab to then replace with further content.

My suggestion would be to do this:

1) Create links to pages with videos embedded in them, with target="_blank".
2) When a user clicks the link, capture it with Javascript (perhaps jQuery) and open the contents of that within some kind of modal overlay like Shadowbox ( http://www.shadowbox-js.com/ ).

This way, the user stays within the same window, without the need for iFrames or new tabs at all. If the user has JS disabled, they'll then get a default "new tab" behavior.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, but I can't use embedded videos at all for my purposes.

Comment: Change this link so instead of a target of `_blank`, use a name. If it's not a frame that exists on the current page (shouldn't be - avoid frames) it will open a new window and give it the label you chose. Any links with the same target will open in the new window. There is one quirk with Chrome in that new pages will only reuse the window if spawned by the same process (which is to say if Page A opens Window B, then Page A is closed/opened in a new window/elsewhere and a link is followed, a third window C will be created, instead of reusing B)

Comment: Will this work when the links being clicked are slightly different, as in they are youtube URLS which have different video IDs, but the domain is the same? (also when you say "new window" are you talking about a popup or a new tab)? Ashwin Singh above is arguing, if I understand correctly, that you can't re-use the same tab if they aren't the same domain, I think

Comment: @user1166981 Try it (but the answer is yes) it's the name that has to match up. HTML Has no concept of tabs - as far as it's concerned, everything is a new window. Specifically, it creates a new frameset with a single frame which some browsers treat as tabs and others treat as popups. What would you expect to happen if someone visited your site using ie6 which doesn't support tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you control that what you want very easily, and if you can find a hook for this, it most likely is not cross-browser. I'm open to a better suggestion but I think you could use javascript [`window.open(URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) and use the same name every time you call it. Then it will replace the previous window. It just will not open in another tab but in a popup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control a webpage in another tab and neither can you limit the no. of tabs a browser can open for obvious reasons of security. Limiting the no. of tabs that can be opened or controlling without user's intervention would definitely be considered hacking, bowsers don't allow that.

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect.  Checkout http://www.efnsports.com, click on forum, it does exactly what I am trying to do. Please avoid using words like "definitely" in future if you are not 100% sure!

Comment: First, you should have mentioned that you meant only tabs of your website should be limited to two. I misunderstood that. Secondly, I don't see the parent page controlling the forums page.

Comment: As far as limiting two windows is concerned you can use <a href="mywebpage" target="_window">My web page</a>, I am not sure about how you will control the second page form parent page if they are not from the same domain. If it were allowed there won't be any need for phishing. As far as my statement is concerned, I stand correct.